# Edit or Remove .KMZ Vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am attempting to trim a previously recorded .kmz line. What I would like to do is remove a few ending vertices that extend beyond the actual end of a hiking trail as well as remove multi-path lines from walking and recording the same small track twice. Is any of this possible or is is impossible to edit these types of files?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that you are able to directly edit an imported KML/KMZ, GPX, or CSV file.

Save your KMZ file as a Shape file, then you should be able to edit the nodes easily.
When you are finished editing the Shape file you can easily export it as a KML file.

Even when it comes to casual use, I try to avoid editing the original data.